# Keeping count within EditorTemplates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way when using EditorTemplates (With Lists) to work out the current list index value? For example in this Editor Template

```
@model myModel

<div class="email-box">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Email)
</div>
```

Can I work out what index in the List I am up to?

EDIt ====

View

```
 @model IEnumerable<myModel>

 @Html.EditorForModel()
```

Editor Template

```
@model myModel
<div class="email-box" rel="@ViewBag.Index">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom Editor templates can accept values when called from the Html extension methods, these values are added to the `ViewBag` specifically for that view. You can use this to send the index of the element into that view

**In the parent view**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyView";
    var index = 0;
}

<h2>My View</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => item, new { Index = index++ })
    </div>
}
```

**In the editor template**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => string.Format("({0} - {1}", ViewBag.Index, m.Description)
```

Comment: I've updated the question, this will work but not in case as I never iterate through the Objects in the model.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually solved this while looking around the available field options.

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix
```

Return [0], [1] etc.. Can just trim this down and we have the ID.